# How can I delete a big part of a string from a scraped page?

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I made a web scraper to get the informative text of a Wikipedia page. I get the text I want but I want to cut off a big part of the bottom text. I already tried some other solutions but with those, I don't get the headers and white-spaces I need.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


website = "https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kat_(dier)"
request = requests.get(website)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")

text = list()

text.extend(soup.findAll('mw-content-text'))

text_content = soup.text
text_content = re.sub(r'==.*?==+', '', text_content)
# text_content = text.replace('\n', '')

print(text_content)
```

Here, `soup.text` is all the text of the wikipedia page with the `class='mw-content-text'` printed as a string. This prints the overall text I need but I need to cut off the string where it starts showing the text of the sources. I already tried the `replace` method but it didn't do anything.

Given this page, I want to cut of what's under the red line in the big string of text I have scraped

[image: screenshot of Wikipedia page with red line]

I tried something like this, which didn't work:

````
  for content in soup('span', {'class': 'mw-content-text'}):
      print(content.text)
      text = content.findAll('p', 'a')
      for t in text:
          print(text.text)```
````

I also tried this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

website = urlopen("https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kat_(dier)").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(website,'lxml')

text = ''

for content in soup.find_all('p'):
    text += content.text

text = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]+', '', text)
text = text.replace('\n', '')

# print(text)
```

but these approaches just gave me an unreadable mess of text. I still want the whitespaces and headers that my base code gives me.

Comment: Can you show in an [edit] as to what you did that didn't work?

Comment: can you share what soup.text is equal to?

Comment: "I want to cut off a big part of the bottom text" ? - Help us to help you and provide more details and expected output

Comment: @JonClements I gave some more explaination, excuse me if it's a bit messy.

Comment: @HedgeHog  I gave some more explaination, excuse me if it's a bit messy.

Comment: @logan_9997 soup.text is all the text of the wikipedia page with the class= 'mw-content-text' printed as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it is still a bit abstract but you could get your goal while iterating over all children and `break` if tag with `class` *appendix* appears:

```
for c in soup.select_one('#mw-content-text > div').find_all(recursive=False):
    if c.get('class') and 'appendix' in c.get('class'):
        break
    print(c.get_text(strip=True))
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

website = "https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kat_(dier)"
request = requests.get(website)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text)

for c in soup.select_one('#mw-content-text > div').find_all(recursive=False):
    if c.get('class') and 'appendix' in c.get('class'):
        break
    print(c.get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: Okay this does work! It does delete some spaces that need to be in the text but I'm sure I can work with this. Thank you!

Comment: If you do not want the stripped text, simply remove stripping and just call `print(c.get_text())`  or `print(c.text)`

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a *more efficient* solution but here is a list comprehension that solves your issue:

```py
# the rest of your code
references = [line for line in text_content.split('\n') if line.startswith("↑")]
```

Heres an alternative version that might be easier to understand:

```py
# the rest of your code

# Turn text_content into a list of lines
text_content = text_content.split('\n')

references = []

# Iterate through each line and only save the values that start 
# with the symbol used for each reference, on wikipedia: "↑" 
# ( or "^" for english wikipedia pages )

for line in text_content:
    if line.startswith("↑"):
        references.append(line)
```

Both scripts will do the same thing.

Comment: I tried this and it works, but it doesn't do what I want. It does isolate the bottem part but I actually want to delete that part of the text.